# PHP. when parsing code to resize images on the fly

Tags: php, html, on-the-fly

I've been told that using this code to resize images on the fly will help speed it up, however i get this error when parsing.

```
<?php
$dirname = "pictures/photos/BITA2015/";
$images = scandir($dirname);
$ignore = Array(".", "..");

foreach($images as $curimg)
{
 if (!in_array($curimg, $ignore))
 {
  echo "<a href=".$dirname.$curimg."><img src="resize.php?file=./pictures/photos/BITA2015/$curimg"/></a>";
 }
}   
?>
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'resize' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in D:\Websites\South Holland\photos.php on line 27

I'm not sure what the resize.php has got to have in it too, but it shouldnt error when parsing surely?

Please help, i need this to pass my college assignment

Comment: Change the quotes to single quotes or escape the double quotes or concatenate the strings between the src quotes correctly

Comment: that's removed the parsing error, thank you, however my images arent displaying still?

Comment: You just want the path in the src attr. nothing else.

Comment: I need the rest of it to get the $curimg to work so that it searches a folder for all pics in there and then displays them